# Partial HTML does not show up using templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the index.html, the code snippet:

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <plantCanvas></plantCanvas>
</body>
```

plantCanvas is a custom directive. So in app.js:

```
angular.module("plantApp", ["ngRoute"])
.controller("AppCtrl",function($scope){
    //
})
.directive("plantCanvas", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: 'partials/canvas.html',
        controller: 'canvasCtrl',
        scope: {
            data: '='
        }
    };
});
```

canvasCtrl is defined in a single file but not implemented yet:

```
function canvasCtrl ($scope) {
    //Nothing here
}
```

Everything in canvas.html is:

```
<div>
    <p>blah</p>
</div>
```

yet nothing shows up.I have tried adding ngRoute as dependency as shown above, but it doesn't change anything. There is no error. I am just so lost as to how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your index.html

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <plant-canvas></plant-canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: It works now but gives another error. I am defining canvasCtrl in another file but it tells me that it is not defined. In the index.html, I have cited both canvasCtrl.js and app.js. Is it possible to do that or I have to write the controller function inside the directive?

Comment: It is possible, just add canvasCtrl to your module and it should work